# how to change a element from a list or use "if else" within a loop to assign element

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am querying a table and am only interested in the "name" column. The table is returned as a list of dictionaries, so I pull the "name" from each entry and add it to a list. The thing is that if the name has a certain value, for instance "N/A" I don't want the new list I am populating to pull in the value "N/A" but another value instead, for instance "skip". Here is an example of what I am doing which doesn't work, and the list stays the same:

```
- name: Extract "name" column from table and append it to new_list
  set_fact:
    new_list: "{{ new_list + [item.name] }}"
  loop: "{{queried_table.record}}"

- name: Iterate through new_list and change "N/A" elements to "skip"
  set_fact:
    current_name: "skip"
  when: current_name == "N/A"
  loop: "{{new_list}}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: current_name
```

What I want to do, but in pseudocode:

```
- name: Extract "name" column from table and append it to new_list
  set_fact:
    new_list: "{{ if(item.name == "N/A"){ 
                      append the word "skip" to new_list instead of "N/A"
                  }else{append item.name onto new_list} 
               }}"
  loop: "{{queried_table.record}}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: ***"Pull 'name' from each entry ... replace 'N/A' with 'skip'."***

A: For example, given the table below for testing

```yaml
queried_table:
  record:
    - {name: r1, rec: data}
    - {name: r2, rec: data}
    - {name: N/A, rec: none}
```

[*map*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.map) the attribute *name* and [*regex_replace*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) the items

```yaml
new_list: "{{ queried_table.record|
              map(attribute='name')|
              map('regex_replace', 'N/A', 'skip')|
              list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
new_list: [r1, r2, skip]
```

Put the declaration of *new_list* into the [*vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) as appropriate.